# UIPanGestureRecognizer to rotate mapView

Tags: ios, mapkit, gesture

I have a method for panning the map using a UIPanGestureRecognizer however it doesn't rotate correctly (I want to be able to make circle motions that cause the camera to move in a circle), is there a better approach here?

```
@objc func panMap (sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .began {
            print("began")
        } else if sender.state == .changed {
            // rotating map camera
            let position = sender.translation(in: mapView)
            let newDirection = mapView.camera.heading.advanced(by: (Double(position.x) + Double(position.y)))
            let newCamera: MKMapCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: mapView.camera.centerCoordinate, fromDistance: mapView.camera.altitude, pitch: mapView.camera.pitch, heading: newDirection)
            mapView.setCamera(newCamera, animated: false)

          // Eugene Dudnyk's solution to help fix logic error when appending distance
          sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: mapView) 

        } else if sender.state == .ended {
            print("end")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: It would be nice to use, however I want to allow the user to only use one finger to rotate the map

Comment: What is `afa / 30`?

Comment: so it rotates the map based on your x-coordinate position your dragging on the map, the divide by 30 reduces the speed of the rotation

Comment: Hey, you can't just modify the problem on-the-go like that. Rotation using just `x` coordinate, and rotation using both `x, y` coordinates are two different rotation approaches. Which one do you really need to use?

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk Sorry about that, I thought that approach would be easier to understand, I tried with just the x coordinate and got the same behavior!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234347/discussion-between-bestfromabove-and-eugene-dudnyk).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `translation` of pan gesture recognizer accumulates relative to the position at the start of panning, but you interpret it as accumulation since the last state change, and always add to the camera angle.

In case if user moved finger to `afa.x = 160`, and then moves finger back, `afa.x` changes let's say from 160 to 150, but you will append to the angle `150 / 30 = 5 degrees` where angle has to be negative, `- 10 / 30 degrees` instead.

Try this, maybe it will make things better:

```
@objc func panMap (sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began {
        print("began")
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        // rotating map camera
        let translation = sender.translation(in: mapView)
        let location = sender.location(in: mapView)
        let bounds = mapView.bounds
        let vector1 = CGVector(dx: location.x - bounds.midX, dy: location.y - bounds.midY)
        let vector2 = CGVector(dx: vector1.dx + translation.x, dy: vector1.dy + translation.y)
        let angle1 = atan2(vector1.dx, vector1.dy)
        let angle2 = atan2(vector2.dx, vector2.dy)
        mapView.camera.heading += (angle2 - angle1) * 180.0 / Double.pi
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        print("end")
    }

    sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: mapView)
}
```

Comment: So this actually helps remove the logic error I made with appending as I move backwards (thanks for that!), however I still cannot make a full rotation as when I make a circle motion clockwise, the second half of the circle motion will move the camera in reverse! I updated the code to represent the new way I calculate distance

Comment: @BestFromAbove See the updated answer - this is proper rotation handling.

Comment: hmm you use local variable 'vector2' before its declaration in line 10. I am going to assume that should be vector1 as well

Comment: Also that same line doesn't have dy: arg, once thats added the solution is perfect and will be accepted as the best answer!

Comment: Yeah, I ported code from objc on the fly, missed that. Now all is set.